# Bootstrap don't have effect in angular 10.2.1

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to use some stuffs from bootstrap, but dont work at all, i realized that only buttons get effect , but the major things ins't work. for example i tried to add this dropdowlist bellow

[image]

but the result is that:

[image]

i add the cdn link direct in html page, and i already install boostrap  via npm, but both cases  the style boostrap and behavior isn't work properly.

[image]

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",

Comment: try add dot before " ./node_modules/bootstrap. See if that helps

Comment: also try to downgrade a bit and use a stable version of bootstrap

Comment: i already tried this before / and ./ stil dont get effect. but its fine will use another way

Comment: Add a code snippet to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add code below to your style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

like the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qej9z.png)